# populating a react-select asynchronously

Tags: react-select

Given a selection made in a react-select (https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/) I am using axios (https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) to grab data from a remote url in order to populate a second react-select on the page.

The trick, which is where I think my use case differs from the Async examples, is that I don't want the user to have to type at all into the second select to trigger the auto-populating. I want that auto-population to happen immediately when the data returns from the AJAX call

I have confirmed that I'm grabbing the remote data correctly, but I can't quite figure out the correct syntax for the `loadOptions` parameter to the react-select. the closest example in the code to what I want is in this function from the project's examples

https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/examples/src/components/GithubUsers.js#L36

thanks for any tips you can offer

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to do a related select type of scenario, where additional arguments are passed that the second select would use, and you require new options on open.

I did this (with the current build) by overriding AsyncSelect and adjusting my loadOptions.

```
import Select from 'react-select/lib/Async';

export default class AsyncSelect extends Select {
  /**
   * reload()
   * Called when optional load arguments change, to reload the
   * data from remote source with new options
   * loadOptions={
   *  (inputValue) => this.props.loadOptions(
   *      inputValue,
   *      this.props.loadArguments
   *    )
   *  }
   */
  reload() {
    this.loadOptions('', options => {
      const isLoading = !!this.lastRequest;
      this.setState({ defaultOptions: options || [], isLoading });
    });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // if the cacheOptions prop changes, clear the cache, force a reload
    if (nextProps.cacheOptions !== this.props.cacheOptions) {
      this.optionsCache = {};
    }
    /**
     * loadArguments
     * Optional property used in the remote request.
     * If these change externally, then the options should be reloaded.
     * This is handy for things like related selects.
     */
    if (nextProps.loadArguments !== this.props.loadArguments) {
      this.reload();
    }
    if (nextProps.defaultOptions !== this.props.defaultOptions) {
      this.setState({
        defaultOptions: Array.isArray(nextProps.defaultOptions)
          ? nextProps.defaultOptions
          : undefined
      });
    }
  }
}
```

And then, in my component:

```
const {loadArguments, myLoadFunc, ...attributes} = this.props;
return (
  <AsyncSelect
    {...attributes}
    className={classes}
    defaultOptions
    loadArguments={loadArguments}
    loadOptions={(inputValue) => myLoadFunc(inputValue, loadArguments)}
    value={selected}
    onChange={this.onChange}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In github async example, input parameter `getUsers(input)` is the search text.

You can store your first react-select value in the component state, than loadOptions promise would fetch endpoint using this state value `firstSelectValue`

```
getUsers() {
   return fetch(`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${this.state.firstSelectValue}`)
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((json) => {
        return { options: json.items };
    });
}
```

Comment: why are you storing the first value in state?